# Is there any method or algo to convert OLAP4j CellSet to json format

Tags: java, spring

I am executing mdx query using olap4j now i need any support by which I can convert this mdx query output to HTML table or in json format

I was trying to use RectangularCellSetFormatter.java but unable to convert it to tabular while it is multilevel result

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.